# exported .obj files have now 3 seperate parts

Tags: mesh, uv

I have an object with 3 separate layers/meshes. I need it to be only 1 layer to import and attached various scripts in unity.
I have brought it into blender and joined the separate meshes so now only one mesh and also one UV layer.
But when I export it out again as a.obj file and then import the .obj file to unity it separate it again into 3 separate layers. am I exporting it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to comment questions, so I have to answer:
I was not able to replicate the problem with different export settings, so I'm guessing it's how you join the meshes.
Did you combine them by pressing 'ctrl+j'?
What are your export settings?

Comment: Hi Yes, I used ctrl + j to combine the meshes  and I can see there is now one layer instead of three previously. The export settings I use are export > wavefront (.obj) and then ticked are ‘apply modifiers’, ‘include edges’, ‘write normals’, ‘include UVs’, ‘write materials’ and ‘objects as OBJ objects’. I exported as a .fbx file also, but the same problem .i.e. when I import into unity the 3 original meshes are on 3 separate layers.

Comment: Could you provide the .blend and/or .fbx? I'm guessing your problem is on the Unity-side of things and would like to test it.

Comment: sure, do you have an email I can get u on? Yes, I think the problem is Maybe with the unity import. thanks

Comment: Hi, I used the Decimater object modifer at 0.1 and this has solved the problem. Many thanks for your help. P